# How to select multiple, inner list elements with lapply in R?

Tags: r, nested, lapply

as a beginner I am grateful for every hint and explanation. I have a nested list with redditors (I was scraping with RedditExtractor) and their about, comments and threads.

[image]

With `lapply` I could select the necessary elements, that I need for further analysis.

```
df_raw_comments_threads <- lapply(all_authors_2019_14_content, `[`, 
                                  c("comments", "threads"))
```

So this worked and next I wanted to select only date_utc and subreddit,

```
df_test_comments_threads <- lapply(df_raw_comments_threads, `[`, 
                                   c("subreddit", "date_utc"))
```

which did not worked because it turned out as "NULL"

[image: !r image description here]

I thought I could do something like this:

`lapply(df_raw_comments_threads[[x]][[i]][[c("date_utc", "subreddit"]])` since the code says: `df_raw_comments_threads[["The_Wombles"]][["comments"]][["date_utc"]]`, though I want `date_utc` und `subreddit` for both, comments and threads and for every `redditor`.

I also tried:

```
df_test_comments_threads <- lapply(df_raw_comments_threads[[]][[i]], 
                                   function(i) "subreddit")

my_list_subset <- df_raw_comments_threads[sapply(df_raw_comments_threads, 
                           function(x) "subreddit")]

df_test_comments_threads <- map(df_raw_comments_threads,
                                "date_utc")

df_test_comments_threads <- lapply(df_raw_comments_threads[[]][["threads"]][["date_utc"]])

df_test_comments_threads <- lapply(all_authors_2019_14_content, `[`,
                                   c("date_utc", "subreddit"))
```

None worked and I am confused why it turned out as NULL since both redditors have entries in every section.

```
str(df_raw_comments_threads)
 $ The_Wombles     :List of 2
  ..$ comments:'data.frame':    1000 obs. of  12 variables:
  .. ..$ url           : chr [1:1000] "https://www.reddit.com/r/nursing/comments/uwk2wj/deleted_by_user/" "https://www.reddit.com/r/nursing/comments/uwk2wj/deleted_by_user/" "https://www.reddit.com/r/nursing/comments/uwk2wj/deleted_by_user/" "https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/uwd8d2/lpt_let_your_daughters_paint_your_nails_have_a/" ...
  .. ..$ date_utc      : chr [1:1000] "2022-05-24" "2022-05-24" "2022-05-24" "2022-05-24" ...
  .. ..$ timestamp     : num [1:1000] 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 ...
  .. ..$ subreddit     : chr [1:1000] "nursing" "nursing" "nursing" "LifeProTips" ...
  .. ..$ thread_author : chr [1:1000] "[deleted]" "[deleted]" "[deleted]" "ckayfish" ...
  .. ..$ comment_author: chr [1:1000] "The_Wombles" "The_Wombles" "The_Wombles" "The_Wombles" ...
  .. ..$ thread_title  : chr [1:1000] "[deleted by user]" "[deleted by user]" "[deleted by user]" "LPT: Let your daughters paint your nails, have a tea party with them, and help them set up a lemon-aid stand. B"| __truncated__ ...
  .. ..$ comment       : chr [1:1000] "Every place is going to be different. because you have EAP you may (depending on your job and the offense) be a"| __truncated__ "Get off your high horse. I suppose you have never made a mistake in your life. Not everything is so black and w"| __truncated__ "For being a sub about nursing a lot of people here don\031t seem to understand addiction." "Lol when you know you know" ...
  .. ..$ score         : num [1:1000] 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 51 10 3 ...
  .. ..$ up            : num [1:1000] 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 51 10 3 ...
  .. ..$ downs         : num [1:1000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..$ golds         : num [1:1000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ threads :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  11 variables:
  .. ..$ url      : chr [1:34] "https://www.reddit.com/gallery/uwivn2" "https://i.redd.it/amr5yi8acjv81.jpg" "https://www.reddit.com/r/copypasta/comments/t8rvfe/i_stopped_smoking_weed_recently_and_guy_fieri_has/" "https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z7603OvpO0" ...
  .. ..$ date_utc : chr [1:34] "2022-05-24" "2022-04-24" "2022-03-07" "2022-01-30" ...
  .. ..$ timestamp: num [1:34] 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.64e+09 1.64e+09 ...
  .. ..$ subreddit: chr [1:34] "Miata" "stihl" "copypasta" "UnsolvedMysteries" ...
  .. ..$ author   : chr [1:34] "The_Wombles" "The_Wombles" "The_Wombles" "The_Wombles" ...
  .. ..$ title    : chr [1:34] "A Diamond in the Dirt" "This Farmboss is almost 30 years old and starts fist pull." "I stopped smoking weed recently and Guy Fieri has been attacking me in my dreams since" "In February 2018, a Toronto firefighter enjoying the last day of his ski trip in New York with friends and coll"| __truncated__ ...
  .. ..$ text     : chr [1:34] "" "" "I stopped smoking weed recently and Guy Fieri has been attacking me in my dreams since\n\nI wasn\031t sure wher"| __truncated__ "" ...
  .. ..$ golds    : num [1:34] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..$ score    : num [1:34] 22 29 7 1 3 ...
  .. ..$ ups      : num [1:34] 22 29 7 1 3 ...
  .. ..$ downs    : num [1:34] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Europa_Teles_BTR:List of 2
  ..$ comments:'data.frame':    1000 obs. of  12 variables:
  .. ..$ url           : chr [1:1000] "https://www.reddit.com/r/Warthunder/comments/grilnr/ww2_german_uboat_submarine_development_19331945/" "https://www.reddit.com/r/HistoriaEmPortugues/comments/grhtvq/sabia_que_madrid_chegou_a_ser_ocupada_pelos/" "https://www.reddit.com/r/Warthunder/comments/grilnr/ww2_german_uboat_submarine_development_19331945/" "https://www.reddit.com/r/Warthunder/comments/gr4zmg/ww2_history_luftwaffe_pilots_studying_the/" ...
  .. ..$ date_utc      : chr [1:1000] "2020-05-27" "2020-05-27" "2020-05-27" "2020-05-26" ...
  .. ..$ timestamp     : num [1:1000] 1.59e+09 1.59e+09 1.59e+09 1.59e+09 1.59e+09 ...
  .. ..$ subreddit     : chr [1:1000] "Warthunder" "HistoriaEmPortugues" "Warthunder" "Warthunder" ...
  .. ..$ thread_author : chr [1:1000] "[deleted]" "fan_of_the_pikachu" "[deleted]" "Europa_Teles_BTR" ...
  .. ..$ comment_author: chr [1:1000] "Europa_Teles_BTR" "Europa_Teles_BTR" "Europa_Teles_BTR" "Europa_Teles_BTR" ...
  .. ..$ thread_title  : chr [1:1000] "WW2 German U-boat (submarine) development, 1933-1945" "Sabia que Madrid chegou a ser ocupada pelos portugueses?" "WW2 German U-boat (submarine) development, 1933-1945" "[WW2 History] Luftwaffe pilots studying the defensive angles of hostile bombers" ...
  .. ..$ comment       : chr [1:1000] "In reply of u/RhodieRanger ; u/aintme_mustbeyou ; u/quietbob515\n\n&amp;#x200B;\n\nTake in mind this post was m"| __truncated__ "Muito interessante, obrigado pela partilha!\n\n&amp;#x200B;\n\ndevia ser partilhado com a malta do r/PORTUGALCARALHO ahah" "In the ['STARFIGHTERS UPDATE / WAR THUNDER'](https://youtu.be/_4s6xOWwXQM?t=349) video by the official War Thun"| __truncated__ "Thank you man =)" ...
  .. ..$ score         : num [1:1000] -1 4 -1 5 62 10 6 1 8 1 ...
  .. ..$ up            : num [1:1000] -1 4 -1 5 62 10 6 1 8 1 ...
  .. ..$ downs         : num [1:1000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..$ golds         : num [1:1000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ threads :'data.frame':    699 obs. of  11 variables:
  .. ..$ url      : chr [1:699] "https://www.reddit.com/r/quotes/comments/9ppwro/faith_is_the_sword_forged_against_fate_europa/" "https://www.reddit.com/r/EuropaTelesBTR/comments/9ppgge/5_reasons_why_you_must_quit_gaming_today/" "https://www.reddit.com/r/EuropaTelesBTR/comments/9ppgge/5_reasons_why_you_must_quit_gaming_today/" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5zN5niz7X0" ...
  .. ..$ date_utc : chr [1:699] "2018-10-20" "2018-10-20" "2018-10-20" "2018-10-19" ...
  .. ..$ timestamp: num [1:699] 1.54e+09 1.54e+09 1.54e+09 1.54e+09 1.54e+09 ...
  .. ..$ subreddit: chr [1:699] "quotes" "StopGaming" "EuropaTelesBTR" "portugal" ...
  .. ..$ author   : chr [1:699] "Europa_Teles_BTR" "Europa_Teles_BTR" "Europa_Teles_BTR" "Europa_Teles_BTR" ...
  .. ..$ title    : chr [1:699] "\"Faith is the sword forged against fate\" - Europa_Teles_BTR" "5 REASONS WHY you must quit gaming TODAY (x-post from r/EuropaTelesBTR)" "5 REASONS WHY you must quit gaming TODAY" "Enfermeiras Pára-quedistas | Guerra colonial Portuguesa [Vídeo] (x-post de r/HistoriaEmPortugues)" ...
  .. ..$ text     : chr [1:699] "" "" "Playing videogames can be seen as a hobby, but it can easily build up into something very destructive and addic"| __truncated__ "" ...
  .. ..$ golds    : num [1:699] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..$ score    : num [1:699] 3 12 9 14 9 70 26 1 7 17 ...
  .. ..$ ups      : num [1:699] 3 12 9 14 9 70 26 1 7 17 ...
  .. ..$ downs    : num [1:699] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the list structure clarified, package {purrr} offers a very concise solution.

```
library(purrr)

## example structure:
all_authors <- list(`The Wombles` = list(comments = structure(list(url = "foo-url1", 
    date_utc = "2022-06-07", score = 3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), threads = structure(list(url = "foo-url2", date_utc = "2022-04-07", 
    title = "title wombles"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))), `The Who` = list(comments = structure(list(url = "foo-url3", 
    date_utc = "2022-06-17", score = 3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), threads = structure(list(url = c("foo-url4", "foo-url5"
), date_utc = c("2022-03-12", "2015-02-04"), title = c("title who", 
"title2 who")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))))


map2_dfr(
  all_authors |> map('comments', ~ pmap(.x, c('url', 'date_utc'))),
  all_authors |> map('threads',  ~ pmap(.x, c('url', 'author', 'title'))),
  ~ list(comments = .x, threads = .y)
)
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  comments$url $date_utc  $score threads$url $date_utc  $title       
  <chr>        <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <chr>      <chr>        
1 foo-url1     2022-06-07      3 foo-url2    2022-04-07 title wombles
2 foo-url3     2022-06-17      3 foo-url4    2022-03-12 title who    
3 foo-url3     2022-06-17      3 foo-url5    2015-02-04 title2 who   
>
```

Comment: I got this error: Error in `vctrs::data_frame()`:
! Can't recycle `comments` (size 1000) to match `threads` (size 34).
So I tried map2() only; it did not select date and subreddit, because they are dfs? So next step was 
df_map_date_sub <- map2(
  df_map_comments_threads |> map(~ .x$comments |> dplyr::select(subreddit, date_utc)),
  df_map_comments_threads |> map(~ .x$threads |> dplyr::select(subreddit, date_utc)),
  ~ list(comments = .x, threads = .y)
) 
and this turned out how I wanted it, really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using package {purrr} anyway, you could apply `map` variants:

example data structure (you forgot to `dput` one):

```
all_authors <- list(The_Wombles = list(about = list(), comments = structure(list(
    url = c("url1", "url2"), date_utc = c("2022-05-24", 
    "2022-05-25")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))), Talking_Foo = list(about = list(), comments = structure(list(
    url = c("url3", "url4"), date_utc = c("2022-05-24", 
    "2022-05-25")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))))
```

use `map`:

```
library(dplyr) ## provides `select`

all_authors |> 
  map(~ .x$comments |> select(url, date_utc))
```

(where `~`is short for the function you apply to each list element and `.x` is short for the list item currently fed into the function: `~ .x` is equivalent to `function(x){x}`)

output:

```
+ $The_Wombles
   url   date_utc
1 url1 2022-05-24
2 url2 2022-05-25

$Talking_Foo
   url   date_utc
1 url3 2022-05-24
2 url4 2022-05-25
```

or `imap_dfr` (dfr = dataframe row) to obtain a dataframe:

```
all_authors |> 
  imap_dfr(~ list(author =.y ,
                  comments = .x$comments |>
                    select(url, date_utc))
           )
```

(where `.y` is short for the name, and `.x` for the content of the list item currently being mapped)

output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  author      comments$url $date_utc 
  <chr>       <chr>        <chr>     
1 The_Wombles url1         2022-05-24
2 The_Wombles url2         2022-05-25
3 Talking_Foo url3         2022-05-24
4 Talking_Foo url4         2022-05-25
```

Comment: library(dplyr) ## provides `select`

all_authors |> 
  map(~ .x$comments |> select(url, date_utc))

This worked perfectly for me! Thanks a lot! I will keep the imap_dfr in mind, seems very useful.

Comment: Good to hear.  BTW, package {purrr} has a number of helpers beyond `map` for list manipulation: https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/main/purrr.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I love the cheat sheets. How could I change the .x$comments so it would take also .x$threads? With map2 I could combine the lists if I would make them separtely? So map2(x,y ~merge). But is there a way I could do map(~ .x$c(comments,threads) |> select(url, date_utc)?

Comment: Please make an example of your data available, e.g. by supplying `str(df_raw_comments_threads)`. It's hard to reconstruct the structure from the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the data, I just changed it in the post.